# failure installing couchbase on node 6.11.5

Tags: node.js, meteor, npm, couchbase

I'm trying to add couchbase@2.1.4 to my node@6.11.5 project but get the following error:

```
npm info build /opt/meteor/dist/bundle/programs/server/npm/node_modules/couchbase
npm info lifecycle couchbase@2.1.4~preinstall: couchbase@2.1.4
npm info linkStuff couchbase@2.1.4
npm verb linkBins couchbase@2.1.4
npm verb linkMans couchbase@2.1.4
npm verb rebuildBundles couchbase@2.1.4
npm info lifecycle couchbase@2.1.4~install: couchbase@2.1.4

> couchbase@2.1.4 install /opt/meteor/dist/bundle/programs/server/npm/node_modules/couchbase
> prebuild --install

module.js:327
    throw err;
    ^

Error: Cannot find module './index'
    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (module.js:325:15)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:276:25)
    at Module.require (module.js:353:17)
    at require (internal/module.js:12:17)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/opt/meteor/dist/bundle/programs/server/npm/node_modules/.bin/rc:2:10)
    at Module._compile (module.js:409:26)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:416:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:343:32)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:300:12)
    at Module.require (module.js:353:17)
npm verb lifecycle couchbase@2.1.4~install: unsafe-perm in lifecycle true
npm verb lifecycle couchbase@2.1.4~install: PATH: /root/.meteor/packages/meteor-tool/.1.5.2_2.fkst7p++os.linux.x86_64+web.browser+web.cordova/mt-os.linux.x86_64/dev_bundle/lib/node_modules/npm/bin/node-gyp-bin:/opt/meteor/dist/bundle/programs/server/npm/node_modules/couchbase/node_modules/.bin:/opt/meteor/dist/bundle/programs/server/npm/node_modules/.bin:/root/.meteor/packages/meteor-tool/.1.5.2_2.fkst7p++os.linux.x86_64+web.browser+web.cordova/mt-os.linux.x86_64/dev_bundle/bin:/root/.meteor/packages/meteor-tool/.1.5.2_2.fkst7p++os.linux.x86_64+web.browser+web.cordova/mt-os.linux.x86_64/dev_bundle/lib/node_modules/npm/bin/node-gyp-bin:/opt/meteor/dist/bundle/programs/server/node_modules/.bin:/root/.meteor/packages/meteor-tool/.1.5.2_2.fkst7p++os.linux.x86_64+web.browser+web.cordova/mt-os.linux.x86_64/dev_bundle/bin:/root/.meteor/packages/meteor-tool/.1.5.2_2.fkst7p++os.linux.x86_64+web.browser+web.cordova/mt-os.linux.x86_64/dev_bundle/lib/node_modules/.bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin
npm verb lifecycle couchbase@2.1.4~install: CWD: /opt/meteor/dist/bundle/programs/server/npm/node_modules/couchbase
npm info lifecycle couchbase@2.1.4~install: Failed to exec install script
npm verb stack Error: couchbase@2.1.4 install: `prebuild --install`
npm verb stack Exit status 1
npm verb stack     at EventEmitter.<anonymous> (/root/.meteor/packages/meteor-tool/.1.5.2_2.fkst7p++os.linux.x86_64+web.browser+web.cordova/mt-os.linux.x86_64/dev_bundle/lib/node_modules/npm/lib/utils/lifecycle.js:279:16)
npm verb stack     at emitTwo (events.js:87:13)
npm verb stack     at EventEmitter.emit (events.js:172:7)
npm verb stack     at ChildProcess.<anonymous> (/root/.meteor/packages/meteor-tool/.1.5.2_2.fkst7p++os.linux.x86_64+web.browser+web.cordova/mt-os.linux.x86_64/dev_bundle/lib/node_modules/npm/lib/utils/spawn.js:40:14)
npm verb stack     at emitTwo (events.js:87:13)
npm verb stack     at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:172:7)
npm verb stack     at maybeClose (internal/child_process.js:862:16)
npm verb stack     at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:222:5)
npm verb pkgid couchbase@2.1.4
npm verb cwd /opt/meteor/dist/bundle/programs/server/npm
npm verb Linux 4.14.131-linuxkit
npm verb argv "/root/.meteor/packages/meteor-tool/.1.5.2_2.fkst7p++os.linux.x86_64+web.browser+web.cordova/mt-os.linux.x86_64/dev_bundle/bin/node" "/root/.meteor/packages/meteor-tool/.1.5.2_2.fkst7p++os.linux.x86_64+web.browser+web.cordova/mt-os.linux.x86_64/dev_bundle/bin/npm" "rebuild" "--update-binary"
npm verb node v4.8.4
npm verb npm  v4.6.1
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 1
npm ERR! couchbase@2.1.4 install: `prebuild --install`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Failed at the couchbase@2.1.4 install script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.
npm verb exit [ 1, true ]

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /root/.meteor/packages/meteor-tool/.1.5.2_2.fkst7p++os.linux.x86_64+web.browser+web.cordova/mt-os.linux.x86_64/dev_bundle/.npm/_logs/2019-10-09T08_37_55_024Z-debug.log
```

I'm completely lost with this. How can I investigate the cause of this. For me the error is not saying much except it is happening in some module not my code I think.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that the couchbase module in this version (2.1.4) does not work on node 6.11.5
Couchbase@2.6.3 works though.